# Type checking in C

Tags: c, types

I am coding the following if-statement:

```
if(chars[a]== char)
{
  do sth;
}
```

My purpose is to test if the element in chars array is a character and if so do something to it. In languages like Python, there is the type function used to find the data type. C doesn't have those. In this case, how can I do something like the above in C?

Comment: Allow me to reverse the question: **why** would you do that? Every element in a char array is a char, so that test is pretty pointless. Do you want/need to know whether the element is alphabetic or a number or something like that?

Comment: yes i want to know  whether its alphabetic or numeric

Comment: Then test that.

Comment: In the bad old days that may have been a bit of a pain to do (unless you conveniently assumed all text was ascii - then it's easy), but nowadays the C library includes the functions `isalpha` and `isdigit` (amongst others - try `man ctype.h`) which make it trivial to do the test you want.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 `isdigit()`, `isalpha()` and friends have existed ever since the K&R days!

Comment: @Ken Y-N They probably did. I know nothing other than what I learned messing about with a Unix V6 emulator, in which I'm pretty sure they didn't exist. But that's pretty darn early stuff.

Answer (score 2):

All the items in a character array are of type char.  Perhaps you mean to check if they are printable characters, in which case you can use `if (isprint(char[a])) {...}`.

`isprint()` is defined in `<ctype.h>` along with other character class tests.

Based on your comment, it looks like you are looking for `isalnum()`

Answer (score 1):

As observed elsewhere, ANYTHING in a char array is a char.  If you want to see about alphas or characters check out isdigit() and isalpha().

There is a C'ism: If you want to know if a char is any from a list, say "asdfjkl" you can run

```
if(strchr("asdfjkl",chars[a]) != NULL  )
{
    oneOfThem();
}
```

The strchr function returns null if the character is not found. In this case, you don't care which one matches, just if it on the list so check for `!= NULL`.  If you are a minimalist programmer, you can also type `(if(strchr())` which will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

C is a statically typed language.  Any variable declared to be a certain type is guaranteed to be that type at run time.

Comment: > C; > strongly typed; These are two terms rarely used in the same breath.

Comment: @Roflcopter4: To paraphrase Rev. Dodgson: “When I use a type,” Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, “it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.” “The question is,” said Alice, “whether you can make types mean so many different things.” “The question is,” said Humpty Dumpty, “which is to be master—that's all.”

Comment: @Bob Jarvis I agree with that sentiment completely. I just know that there are many who very much do not agree with that sentiment, and many who can't seem to mention C and its type system without washing their hands afterwards.

Comment: Washing their hands? I'd suggest a shower. Hot water. Lots of soap. :-)

Comment: Still better than JavaScript.